# Deploying a report local URL not working

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I'm trying to use MS Reporting Services. So far I have been able to create a simple report, using the *AdventureWorks* database.

Next step I wanted to take was to deploy my report. This is what I did:

1. In the *Business Intelligence* editor I right-clicked on the project name and clicked properties
2. I added a *Start Item* and I set the `TargetServerURL` to the URL that was displayed in the *Reporting Services Configuration Manager*. The URL is: `http://ADMIN-PC:80/ReportServer`
3. After that I clicked "OK" to go out of the Properties window. Then I hit *Build Report Project1* in the *Build* menu.

After it tries to build it gives me the following error:

> The specified report server URL: "http://admin-pc/ReportServer" could
>   not be found. Verify the syntax of the URL and that the report server
>   exists.

I'm sure the URL is correct. Or at least, that is what the *Reporting Services Configuration Manager* says.

So I have no clue what to check next in order to fix this problem. Anyone any idea what to do?

Comment: What happens if you go to `http://admin-pc/reports`? Does it show the web dashboard? (Also, did you check and/or find anything useful in the [relevant documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630447.aspx)?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's always tough to try and troubleshoot these general "it's not working" errors, but here's a rough idea of what I'd try looking at:

1. **Is the service running?** If you can connect through *Reporting Services Configuration Manager* then the answer is probably yes, but it's always the first thing to check!
2. **Are the URLs correct?** You may need to check you're using the correct URLs - these can be confirmed through *Reporting Services Configuration Manager*; by default Named Instances will have URLs like `http://admin-pc/ReportServer_InstanceName` and `http://admin-pc/Reports_InstanceName`.
3. **Can I connect out of BIDS?** What happens when you connect to `http://admin-pc/ReportServer` through Internet Explorer? What about `http://admin-pc/Reports`?
4. **Are there permission issues?** By default the only users that can access SSRS are those in the `BUILTIN\Administrators` group. Is your user in this group?
5. **Is UAC mucking me up?** As above, only Administrators will have default access, but if UAC is enabled you still won't connect as an admin even if you're in this group. Try running BIDS or Internet Explorer with `Run As Administrator` and see if it makes any difference.
6. **Is the URL being registered successfully?** The URLs won't work if the port is already in use, but `Reporting Services Configuration Manager` will quite happily allow you to set this without an error even if the port's in use; it's especially when using port 80. 
   Check the log file at `Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\<SSRSInstance>\Reporting Services\LogFiles`; this will have an error logged if it can't register the URL on the port specified. If you see an error here try a different port.
7. **Any other errors in the log?** Failing this, check the log for any more errors.

Not much to go on, I admit, but maybe there's something you haven't looked at here. I'd saying stepping through these checks has solved 99% of the errors that I've seen in the past.

Comment: Your troubleshooting "guide" helped me out! :) I forgot that i still had Apache running (from my last project). So step 5 was the problem i had. I changed the port of `Reporting Services` from `80` to `8002` and all seems to be working now. Thanks for your help.